# How to get the integer values from the String

Tags: java, android

My String is like

```
String body = "GH 1234 RING 5";
```

I want to extract the number 1234, RING and last 5 into separate variables and want  to compare each of those values..It will be like..
pass = 1234, cmnd = RING and duration = 5 like this..
Please help me to figure out how to achieve this.
Im doing like

```
String body="GH 1234 RING";
String pass=bodypass = body.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

to get the 1234 in it.But i cant find how  to retrieve RING and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
String body = "GH 1234 RING 5";
String[] splited = body.split("\\s+");
```

Now this will be the result

```
splited[0] = GH
splited[1] = 1234
splited[2] = RING
splited[3] = 5
```

Comment: but this splits the string because of a whitespace, isn´t it or am I wrong? And if yes, what about if the string is without whitespaces?

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much @Rohit5k32 it Works.!!!!

Comment: @PrudhviRajKumar If it works for you then don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: yeah I accepted the answer..!! and it works like a charm too...!!!